# Take a snapshot with "PrtScn" Key doesn't work with classical Gnome

Tags: gnome-classic

If I press the "PrtScn" button the UI flashes white but the following Save Dialog doesn't open.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with the classical Gnome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, but the screenshot is saved in your `~/Pictures` folder.